# Save an answer as a draft

Tags: support, answers

I was wondering if it couldn't be a good feature to be able to save an answer as a draft in case I don't yet want to post it since I may be doing something else with my machine before later completing the answer to be posted?

This feature does not exist yet, it could be nice to have it around, in my opinion. I am open to knowing more. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature already exists. Try writing an answer. Wait for about 30-45 seconds. ***Draft Saved*** will appear and a **Discard** button too.

[image: Screenshot]

---

**A secret:**

> There was  a [secret hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319840/468333) just for discarding the draft in [Winter Bash 2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/) and [Winter Bash 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019/).
> **Rubber Ducky:**
> [image]

---

From [waffles' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111578/468333) on [What are the details/implementation of the draft feature? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111050/468333):

> Drafts are stored in redis for 7 days, with each site having storage
> for one draft question and one draft answer per user.
>
> For anonymous we use cookie to track the user. For non anonymous we
> use the user id.
>
> We ship it to the server in the heartbeat (once a minute or so), the
> heartbeat also notifies you when new answers were added in the banner
> on the top.
>
> We only store drafts for new answers and new questions, not for edits.

Also, for questions, only one draft is saved which can be retrieved after you click on ***Ask a question*** button. For answers, you should be lucky enough to find the question to find the answer's draft.

From [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361485/10785056) on [How can I find my saved draft answers? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361479/10785056):

> There is no page on the Stack Overflow site with a list of your drafts, and since the drafts are stored server-side, you cannot browse your local storage / cookies for question IDs.

#### Further Reading:

- Proposal for the feature: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/468333)

Comment: Okay, I see... Well understood.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "Discard" button. For some reason, I hadn't noticed it!

Comment: @DKBose "Discard" just reminded me of a secret. I just revealed that ;)